# How to run .Net code in visual studio code?

Tags: c#, .net

I am trying to make a simple hello world application on Visual Studio Code for Mac. I am following the tutorial from [this](https://www.microsoft.com/net/tutorials/csharp/getting-started/hello-world) website by Microsoft.

As far as I can tell, there is no button I can click to run my application and output the results of it... I tried to configure a task from [this](https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/editor/tasks) website, and when I try to "configure a task runner", it says "tasks are only available in a workspace folder".

Can someone please explain to me how I can run my simple application on visual studio code for Mac?

Comment: Are you running .NET Core or the full 4.6 framework?

Comment: @alex .... https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/languages/csharp   try this ..

Comment: @Webbanditten, can you run .NET 4.6 on Mac?

Comment: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=B-v58Yf07RE  ... See This For Tutorial .. How You Can .

Comment: @Fabio No you can run the full .NET 4.6 framework on Mac, thats why Im asking him what framework and version hes trying to run.

Comment: @Webbanditten, you can not run .NET 4.6 on Mac OS as it is. You will need to use virtual machine or some other runtime envoronment (ex. Mono)

Comment: I literally just wrote that @fabio

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Figured it out. All you have to do is press fn + F5 on mac and it'll run the code...

[This](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=t4heVCEe3u8) video was very helpful in teaching how to do it.